# jquery function deactivates after page refresh even if it shouldn't

Tags: php, jquery

im having this problem. In jQuery i have this thing: when you start writing in input the "name_placeholder" gets smaller and changes, because it gets new class, but i have some PHP and SQL there, so after submitting, it "refreshes" and that "name_placeholder" gets back to its position even when it shouldn't.

So basically... when input is empty, "name_placeholder" doesnt have class and when in input is any text "name_placeholder" gets new class named "active", but when you submit the form, page refreshes, but cause of that PHP stuff, forms are still filled so "name_placeholder" should have class named "active", but it doesn't. Can you help me ??

```html
<input type="text" name="name" class="name" value="<?php value('name') ?>" />
<p class="name_placeholder">Your name</p><?php name() ?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.name').on('input', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
      $('.name_placeholder').removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.name_placeholder').addClass('active');
      }
  });
});
```

btw. ignore that PHP stuff, it's just when you fill it wrong, the values will stay there and will not be deleted

Comment: its in separated file. I have it linked in head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this one of two ways (or three):

A) Handle it in PHP when you build your output. Add the class if it will have a value.

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="name" value="<?php value('name');?>" />
<p class="name_placeholder<?php echo (name()?' active':'');?>">Your name</p><?php name();?>
```

---

Or

B) Adjust your js to check your input and determine if it has a value and add the class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.name').val() !== '') {
        $('.name_placeholder').addClass('active');
    }
    $('.name').on('input', function() {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $('.name_placeholder').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.name_placeholder').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

---

Or

However if you want to mass-handle the above (where you have multiple inputs and different names of each), you could adjust your code a bit as such:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="name hyperactive" value="<?php value('name');?>" />
<p class="name_placeholder">Your name</p><?php name();?>
<input type="text" name="email" class="email hyperactive" value="<?php value('email');?>"/>
<p class="email_placeholder">Your email</p><?php email();?>
```

JS:

```
function hyperActive(item) {
    if (item.val() === '') {
        $('.'+ item.attr('name') +'_placeholder').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.'+ item.attr('name') +'_placeholder').addClass('active');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    // both of these MUST be in your .ready block

    // the following will handle them all on page load to setup classes
    $(".hyperactive").each(function(){
        hyperActive( $(this) );
    });

    // the following then handles the action events on input typing
    $('.hyperactive').on('input', function() {
        hyperActive( $(this) );
   });
});
```

Just make sure each of your `*_placeholder` are named to match the `input name` its tied too, and it will handle all the elements with just that code.

Comment: thank you very much, i used your method B and it worked :D

Answer (score 1):

The callback you wrote executes on input on your text box:

```
$('.name').on('input', ....)
```

You have to execute it both at page load and on input. The best way is to separate the callback into a separate function:

```
function test() {
    if ($('.name').val() === '') {
      $('.name_placeholder').removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.name_placeholder').addClass('active');
    }
}    

$(document).ready(test); // executes at page load
$('.name').on('input', test); // executes at every input
```

Comment: i tried this and it worked too. Same like that method B down there :D